# 2 MySQL SELECT Statements in one PHP query

Tags: mysql, sql, statements

How cand I put the following two MySQL `SELECT` statements in one `PHP` query?

```
$SQLquery = "SELECT MAX(ID) AS last_id FROM table";
$SQLquery = "SELECT full_name FROM table";
```

Thanks, and a nice day.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to get a username of the user who has max ID?

Please specify what you would like to achieve with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest record without using `MAX`,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
ORDER   BY ID DESC
LIMIT   1
```

But if you certainly want to use `MAX`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tableName)
```